# 'doc is missing path' when trying to patch with Kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I'm trying to replace `RAILS_ENV`env variable defined in this Deployment file.

`deploy.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myservice-web
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myservice-web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myservice-web
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: myservice-web-sa
      nodeSelector:
        iam.gke.io/gke-metadata-server-enabled: "true"
      containers:
        - name: myservice-web
          image: us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/path/to/myimage
          args:
            - bundle 
            - exec 
            - bin/rails 
            - server 
            - -p 
            - "3000" 
            - -b 
            - "0.0.0.0"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "2Gi"
              cpu: 1
            limits:
              memory: "2Gi"
              cpu: 1
          env:
            - name: RAILS_ENV
              value: "production"
            - name: RACK_ENV
              value: "production"
            - name: NODE_ENV
              value: "production"
            - name: SECRETS_PATH
              value: "/var/myservice-secrets"
            - name: SECRETS_FILE
              value: ".secrets"
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: "/var/myservice-secrets"
              name: gcp-myservice-secrets
      initContainers:
        - name: migrations
          image: us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/path/to/myservice:develop
          command:
          - bundle
          - exec
          - bin/rails
          - db:migrate
          env:
          - name: RAILS_ENV
            value: "production"
          - name: RACK_ENV
            value: "production"
          - name: NODE_ENV
            value: "production"
          - name: SECRETS_PATH
            value: "/var/myservice-secrets"
          - name: SECRETS_FILE
            value: ".secrets"
          volumeMounts:
          ...
      imagePullSecrets: 
      ...
      volumes:
      ...
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myservice-web
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: myservice-web
```

This is the kustomization file:

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

namespace: default

bases:
  - ../../base

images:
  - name: us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/path/to/myimage
    newTag: develop

resources:
  - sa.yaml
  - ing.yaml
  - ing-jukeboxhealth.yaml
  - cert.yaml
  - cert-jukeboxhealth.yaml

patches:
- patch: |-
    - op: replace
      path: /spec/template/spec/containers/0/env[name="RAILS_ENV"]/value
      value: "staging"
  target:
    kind: Deployment
    name: myservice-web
```

I get this error:

```
error: replace operation does not apply: doc is missing path: /spec/template/spec/containers/0/env[name="RAILS_ENV"]/value: missing value
```

I've tried defining the path by position instead of name and it works. But I'd like to do it by targeting the name. What is wrong with the path?

Comment: [Array element election by `key=value` is not supported](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/4509). See also the [relevant section of the corresponding RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901#section-4). --- Out of curiosity: have you tried a strategic merge patch instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kustomize patching a specific container other than by array (/containers/0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63927916/kustomize-patching-a-specific-container-other-than-by-array-containers-0)

Comment: @Turing85 I haven't. I'm new to Kubernetes. But thanks for pointing it out! I'll dig more into strategic merge patch.

Answer (score 0):

The above error due to path.
Try this path:

`/spec/template/spec/containers/0/env/0/value`

in the kustomization file.